# java excel to pdf conversion

Tags: java, excel, pdf, pdf-conversion

I need to convert **xlsx** documents to **pdf** format.
I know that **iText** can save pdf documents and **Docx4j** can read and write xslx.
In fact our application use both for building reports.
But we have very difficult templates so I can't just read xslx(docx4j) and write it to pdf(iText). The formatting will be lost, so I need another conversion lib.
I also heard about commercial libraries like ([Jxcell](http://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.jxcell.net) ) but want to use open source solution.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be done in Java?
If yes, maybe take a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org)

Otherwise, why not have a small native app that utilises a PDF Printer, and calls the relevant APIs to print the file directly to PDF? Surely Java is not really made for doing this kind of work...

For example here's a Non-Java framework for that: [PDF Class Library from Solidworks](http://www.soliddocuments.com/products.htm?product=SolidFramework)

Comment: as far as I know POI can't work with xslx and I need not to create new document but convert the exsisting one. Only Java is allowed(((

Answer (score 3):

i have using iText and apache poi:

```
    FileInputStream filecontent = new FileInputStream(new File(sourcepath));
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationPath));
    HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = null;
    HSSFSheet my_worksheet = null;
    XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = null;
    XSSFSheet my_worksheet_xlsx = null;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.ARCH_E, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
    document.open();
    PdfDestination magnify = null;
    float magnifyOpt = (float) 70.0;
    magnify = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, -1, -1, magnifyOpt / 100);
    int pageNumberToOpenTo = 1;
    PdfAction zoom = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(pageNumberToOpenTo, magnify, writer);
    writer.setOpenAction(zoom);
    document.addDocListener(writer);

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = null;
    int maxColumn = 0;
    if (fileType.equals(".xls")) {
        try {
            my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(filecontent);
            my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator();
            maxColumn = my_worksheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PdfConversion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    if (fileType.equals(".xlsx")) {
        try {
            my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filecontent);
            my_worksheet_xlsx = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            rowIterator = my_worksheet_xlsx.iterator();
            maxColumn = my_worksheet_xlsx.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PdfConversion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    PdfPTable my_table = new PdfPTable(maxColumn);
    my_table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    my_table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    my_table.setSpacingBefore(0f);
    my_table.setSpacingAfter(0f);
    PdfPCell table_cell;
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); //Fetch CELL
            switch (cell.getCellType()) { //Identify CELL type
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    //Push the data from Excel to PDF Cell
                    table_cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                    if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                        table_cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
                        table_cell.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
                    }
                    my_table.addCell(table_cell);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    document.add(my_table);
    document.close();
    System.out.println("Excel file converted to PDF successfully");
```

Comment: try to provide imports will make our life a lot easier. thanks mate