# Send Request for convert xlsx file into pdf to the Microsoft Office or Google Sheet from My app

Tags: android, pdf, google-sheets, itext, xlsx

I am android developer creating app that create `xlsx` file.  My aim is to convert that `xlsx` file to `PDF` but creating `PDF` from `xlsx` is more complicated that you need to download `itext` lib then iterates all column and then rows and add one by one into `pdf` file [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54428098/4741746) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116503/4741746). This operation is more complex when you have `xlsx` file with large tables, column having wired table format, text style, font and text format etc. After conversion it not perfectly match as `xlsx` file.  Currently  My app send intent request to payment getaway app "easy pay"  for doing payment and return success or failure in my on activity result . Similarly I want Microsoft Office, Google Sheet app to `convert` xlsx `to PDF` for me they accept xlsx file path and return pdf file path

***Microsoft Office*, *Google Sheet*** convert `xlsx` to `pdf` exactly as they appear but don't know how they do that, If anybody know that code  please share with me or  if they can accept other app request like below then how to do that?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("packageNameOfOfficeOrGoogleSheet", "activityName");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(PATH,pathOfXlsxFile);
try 
{
    startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode)
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    Toast.makeText(context,"Activity Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I comprehend that you want to convert a `XLSX` file to a `PDF` and want to do it by using Google Sheets. You are very close to doing it, you only need to use Google Drive instead.

To start the operation you should upload the `XLSX` file as usual. After that, use [`Files.export()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) from Drive API with the Sheet identifier and the `PDF` MIME type (`application/pdf`). The response will include a `PDF` file based on your spreadsheet. Please, ask me any additional doubt to help you better.

Comment: can you please share some code snap and also let me know which lib i need to add for google drive api